# Why isn't Chrome rendering images and fonts correctly?

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

I have an Acer monitor and an Intel Pentium 4 running 12.04 32-bit.

Chrome renders all webpages like this:

[image]

This is how CNN *should* look:

[image]

I have Firefox installed and its images/fonts look fine.

I am new to Ubuntu and comfortable with using Terminal. Beyond that, I have no idea what I'm doing. This happened all of a sudden a few weeks ago.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you restart your system and the issue doesn't go away, then you are hitting a bug. Upgrade to 14.04 and check.

Answer (score 2):

First see whether it has the same effect when you execute this command in your Terminal:

> sudo google-chrome --enable-webgl --ignore-gpu-blacklist --user-data-dir --enable-font-antialiasing

or this:

> sudo google-chrome --disable-gpu --user-data-dir --enable-font-antialiasing

---

Chrome has many different bugs regarding font rendering.

I suggest you to install Chrome's open source sibling `Chromium` by executing the below commands in your Terminal:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:saiarcot895/chromium-beta
>   sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get install chromium-browser

Comment: Don't run chrome with `sudo` - there's no reason to run a web browser as root.